# ORDER BY ASC DESC & LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I would to do something such as:

```
SELECT Position INTO lastPosition FROM ranking 
ORDER BY ranking.Time DESC ranking.Position DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but i get this error:

[image]

and:

[image]

and:

[image]

The goal is to select last row (limit 1) of `ranking` ordered by descendent `position` and `ascendent` time.

---

#### Update

The problem was a missing comma after the first DESC, the correct statement is

```
SELECT Position INTO lastPosition FROM ranking 
ORDER BY ranking.Time DESC, ranking.Position DESC LIMIT 1;
```

as noticed @Solarflare.

Comment: Around here, you get minus one for phrases like "doesn't work", so I'll start the ball rolling...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that it does not work? What's the error message or unexpected behaviour you encounter?

Comment: Is the above statement inside a stored proc / function or outside of it?

Comment: You are missing a comma after the first `desc`. And what do you want to get? The last row? Then you have to reverse your order and take the first.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the missing comma. Now it's okay with: `...
ORDER BY ranking.Time DESC, ranking.Position DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: You could just delete the question as it is not going anywhere unless you self answer it

Comment: Hope it's right now. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was **a missing comma** after the first DESC, the correct statement is

```
SELECT Position INTO lastPosition FROM ranking 
ORDER BY ranking.Time DESC, ranking.Position DESC LIMIT 1;
```

as noticed by [@Solarflare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6248528/solarflare).